# Golang - CSRF token mismatch

Tags: go

I am a newbie with Go.
I have a problem I can't figure out. I am using gin-csrf package to protect API from CSRF attack.

```
store := cookie.NewStore([]byte("secret"))
    private.Use(sessions.Sessions("mysession", store))
    private.Use(csrf.Middleware(csrf.Options{
        Secret: "secret123",
        ErrorFunc: func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.String(400, "CSRF token mismatch")
            c.Abort()
        },
    }))
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
CSRF token mismatch
```

What am I missing and/or doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the package, and a little more code so we can get an idea of what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply     https://github.com/utrack/gin-csrf